# TypeError: MongoClient.model is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this error but I don't know where it comes from: C:\Users\nicol\RESTAPI\model\posts.js:3
const PostsCatdog = MongoClient.model(
^

TypeError: MongoClient.model is not a function

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const PostsCatdog = MongoClient.model(
    "Catdog-api",
    {
        dog : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        cat : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
    },
    "posts"
);
module.exports = { PostsCatdog };
```

And my code is that.
Please help me.

I tried to reinstall mongo to change to rephrase my line but nothing to do

Comment: Mongoose and MongoClient are not the same thing.  `.model` is a mongoose method.

Comment: please refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: What should you use with mongodb then?